# How to get count of specific property from responseBody of the streamReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Hello I want to store count of a specific data in database, it's a custome middleware for store logs in database, every actions in controllers return a responseResultObkect Which has some properties of course result, it sould get the result property of that objectresult and gives count of the results, I don't know I could explained it good or not but I share the code I hope you can help me,thanks a lot.

```
 public ChallengeMiddleware(RequestDelegate RequestDelegate)
        {
            if (RequestDelegate == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(RequestDelegate)
                    , nameof(RequestDelegate) + " is required");
            }

            _request = RequestDelegate;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext Context, ILogService logService,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IExceptionService2 exceptionService)
        {
            Stream originalBody = Context.Response.Body;
            ServiceLog logMetadata = await LogRequest(Context);
            try
            {
                if (Context == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Context)
                        , nameof(Context) + " is required");
                }

                //****************************** Response *************************************

                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    string errorMsg = "";

                    //Stream originalBody = Context.Response.Body;
                    Context.Response.Body = memStream;

                    await _request(Context);
                    var controllerName = Context.GetRouteData().Values["controller"];
                    var actionName = Context.GetRouteData().Values["action"];
                    if (controllerName != null)
                    {
                        logMetadata.ControllerName = controllerName.ToString();
                    }
                    if (actionName != null)
                    {
                        logMetadata.ActionName = actionName.ToString();
                    }
                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    string responseBody = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();
                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);

                    if (Context.Response.StatusCode != (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        switch (Context.Response.StatusCode)
                        {
                            case (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                                errorMsg = "دسترسی شما مجاز نمیباشد";
                                break;
                            case (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                                errorMsg = "درخواست شما قابل اجرا نیست";
                                break;
                            case (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                                errorMsg = "درخواست ارسالی شما معتبر نیست";
                                break;
                            case (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                                errorMsg = "درخواست شما با خطا مواجهه شده است";
                                break;
                        }
                        Context.Response.Body = originalBody;
                       
                    }

                    var routeData = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData();
                    var apiKey = routeData.Values["ApiKey"];
                    if (apiKey != null)
                    {
                        var apiKeyString = apiKey.ToString();
                        logMetadata.requestContent = apiKeyString;
                    }

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(responseBody))
                        try
                        {
                           
                            dynamic objectResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
                            var count = 0;
                            
                            foreach (var item in objectResult)
                            {
                                var result = item.First.result;
                                if(result!= null)
                                    count++;
                            }
                            var count2 = count;
                            

                        }
                        catch (System.Exception e)
                        {
                            logMetadata.responseOtherContent = responseBody;
                           
                        }
                }

                logMetadata.responseContentType = Context.Response.ContentType;
                logMetadata.responseDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                logMetadata.responseStatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)Context.Response.StatusCode;
                logService.addAddServiceLog(logMetadata);

                //****************************** End Response *************************************
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                Context.Response.Body = originalBody;
                logMetadata.responseResultObject = WriteErrorObjectResultResponse(Context, e.Message);
                logMetadata.responseContentType = Context.Response.ContentType;
                logMetadata.responseDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                logMetadata.responseStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                logService.addAddServiceLog(logMetadata);
            }
        }
```

and this is for example my login controller:

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(DTOUserForLogin userForLoginDTO)
        {
            // Check if username exists and if the username exists check if the username/ password combination is valid
            var userFromRepo = await _Service.Login(userForLoginDTO.UserName.ToLower(), userForLoginDTO.Password);

            // if username does not exist or username/password combination invalid break out of login process & return error
            if (userFromRepo == null)
                return await UserNotExist();
            else
            if (!userFromRepo.Active)
                return await UserNotActive();

            DTOUserDetails usersToReturn = new DTOUserDetails()
            {
                Created = userFromRepo.Created,
                Id = userFromRepo.ID,
                LastActive = userFromRepo.LastActive,
                Owner = userFromRepo.Owner,
                UserName = userFromRepo.UserName
            };

            // Fill Lazy Load Current User With All Childs Entity
            // CurrentUser = await _userService.GetByID(userFromRepo.ID, DefaultIncludes.UserDefaultIncludes);
            string token = new TokenService(_Config).CreateToken(userFromRepo);

            DTOUserWithToken dTOUserWithToken = new DTOUserWithToken();
            dTOUserWithToken.Token = token;
            dTOUserWithToken.User = usersToReturn;
            // send token
            resultObject = new DTOResultObject(dTOUserWithToken);
            //return new OkObjectResult(new List<long> { 1, 2 });
            return new OkObjectResult(resultObject);
        }
```

and this is my objectresult class :

```
 public class DTOResultObject
    {
        public DTOResultObject()
        {

        }
        public DTOResultObject(string singleMessage)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(singleMessage))
            {
                serverErrors = new List<DTOError>();
                //serverErrors.Add(new DTOError() { Message = singleMessage });
            }
        }
        public DTOResultObject(object _Result)
        {
            Result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_Result);
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int logId { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public ServiceLog log { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore] 
        public List<DTOError> serverErrors { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }
```

for example,  my login controller if the login was successful, returns a DtoObjectResult that has a json web token in it's result property, so we have one result property, I want to save that number one in database as result count in my log table, excatly this piece of challengeMiddleWare Code:

```
   responseBody = responseBody.Replace(@"\", " ");
 
                            dynamic objectResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
                            var count = 0;
                            
                            foreach (var item in objectResult)
                            {
                                var result = item.First.result;
                                if(result!= null)
                                    count++;
                            }
                            var count2 = count;
```

When I trace the code,for example when I call the : "Register"Action that sould retruns the data of the registered user, the value of the : objectResult variable is :

```
{{
  "id": 0,
  "logId": 0,
  "log": null,
  "serverErrors": null,
  "result": "[{\"Id\":27,\"Owner\":\"admin9\",\"UserName\":\"admin9\",\"Created\":\"2023-06-07T17:11:17.2434468+03:30\",\"LastActive\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\"}]"
}}
```

I want number 1 for the count variable, because we only have one result for the "result" section,
but unfortunately it gives me number 5, means the count of properties in DTOResultObject class such as id,logId,log,serverErrors and the result property, but I want the numbers of the results in the result property, could you please help me what can I do? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to get how many sets of json data are in the `result` property, and you can process the `result` separately:

```
dynamic objectResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
var count = 0;
var objResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectResult.result).Trim('\"').Replace(@"\", " ");
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(objResult);

foreach (var item in list)
{
    var result = item;
    if (result != null)
        count++;
}
var count2 = count;
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello @Chen,Fist of all thanks a lot for your help, but unfortunately it said that the objectresult.result is null and it's threw null reference exception to me,could you please send the whole code?

Comment: Actually It said the result of responsebody is null  I don't know why